# L20n.js: localize dynamically created strings

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, l20n

In my app I can localize most of strings via tags, as it is described in l20n.js docs. But sometimes I have to localize dynamycally created strings. Like: `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "some text";`

I use Polymer and custom web components, so the main goal is to create one function for any localization case. 
If i try `document.l10n.get(string);`, I get `TypeError: document.l10n.get is not a function`.

What is the best way to do it? Could not find the solution in official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `document.l10n` is an instance of the L20n's `View` class, you can use the `formatValue` and `formatValues` methods for your use-case.  Please see the [documentation](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/2ce0276fe5b3f5c971d7bdcf24e41d0d29ce81b6/docs/view.md#viewformatvalueid-args) for details.

Both methods return promises so you'll need to do something like the following:

```
document.l10n.formatValue('hello', { who: 'world' }).then(
  hello => document.getElementById(id).textContent = hello
);
```

You can assign to `textContent` or `innerHTML`.  Keep in mind that L20n allows for HTML in translations and it only sanitizes them when using the declarative `data-l10n-id` approach.  So if you want to manually assign to `innerHTML` you might want to make sure you trust the content of the translations.  In the future I'd like to add a special API to apply translations to DOM elements using the same sanitization as the declarative method (bug [1228021](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228021)).